# Find derivative graphically by estimating slopes

Tags: calculus, functions

> Directions: Estimate the slope on the curves for different x-values. Plot the points from your table on the axes and draw a smooth curve through them. This represents the graph of your derivative function.

On the graph I took the points $(-1,4)$ and $(1,0)$, which gave me a slope of $-2$. Since the graph is linear, would my $f'(x)$ values in the table below just all be $-2$? And would the graph of the derivative be exactly the same as the one below?

[image: Calc graph]

Comment: The values would all be -2, that is correct.  The graph of y = -2 does not look like the line in the given graph however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the derivative does appear to be -2 everywhere, that doesn't make the graph of the original function the same as the graph of the derivative (indeed, this doesn't happen for most functions).  Instead, $F'(x)=-2$, which gives simply a horizontal line at $y=-2$.a

Comment: Right! Thanks a lot.